# Compiling php with MySQL support problems

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php

I am attempting to get MySQL working in PHP on CentOS with Apache that was installed from source by some one else. PHP was also installed from source so yum install php-mysql doesnt work though it does work for CLI PHP but thats not the php apache is using. I have downloaded the new source for php and installed it to replace the old php. My config command was

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs --with-MySQL=/usr/local/mysql --prefix=/usr/local/php --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php --disable-cgi --with-zlib --with-gettext --with-gdbm
```

At this point I cant get any mysql code to work and phpinfo() does not show info for MySQL but it does show the above configure command. It maybe something I need to change in my php.ini. Alternatively if I can just use php installed with yum that would work. Just it would need to know php is installed at /usr/local/apache/ or that I need the libphp5.so module for the yum installed php and not the one compiled from source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of PHP? If 5.3 or higher, you could try:

```
--with-mysql=mysqlnd
```

That's the mysql native driver that php started using in php 5.3

Also, in case you haven't, browse through the installation instructions here if it's not 5.3:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php

Comment: Thanks a million, recompiled with that flag and it worked like a charm.